# How to read data from USB in robot framework using serial library?

Tags: serial-port, robotframework, pyserial, usbserial

I need to automate the USB devices that are connected to USB ports in robot framework. But I am struck in beginning itself as I do not know how to open the port. My questions are as below:

1. Do we need to convert USB port to serial port for automation testing?
2. If not then how to find the port locator while opening the port specially USB devices.
3. As I researched, USB ports and serial ports work differently. If that is the case which library we should use for USB port testing.

PF my inline code as well and please help.

```
Open Serial Port
  Add Port  Port_#0002.Hub_#0001
    ...        baudrate=115200
    ...        bytesize=8
    ...        parity=N
    ...        stopbits=1
    ...        timeout=999


*** Test Cases ***
Port able to listen or not
  [Documentation]  Port is working fine or not
  [Tags]  Listen Feature
  Open Serial Port

  ${out}  List Com Ports
  Log  ${out}
  ${out}  Get Current Port Locator
  Log  ${out}
  read all and log
```